# ant design recursive nested table don't work

Tags: reactjs, antd

i want to use  recursive nested table in react's component framework:antd, but it doesn't  work like this :

```
import {Table, Badge, Menu, Dropdown, Icon} from 'antd';
export  default  class TreeTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            nestedData: []
        }
    }



    expandedRowRender(e) {

        const nested_source = e.nest_data

        const columns = this.props.nest_columns

        return (
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={nested_source}
                pagination={false}
                expandedRowRender={(e)=>{this.expandedRowRender(e)}}
                title={()=>"一级岗位列表"}
                showHeader={false}
                size={"middle"}
            />

        );
    }

    render() {
        const data_source = this.props.data_source.map((v, i)=> {
            return {key: i, ...v}
        })

        return (
            <div >
                <Table
                    className="components-table-demo-nested"
                    columns={this.props.columns}
                    expandedRowRender={(e)=>::this.expandedRowRender(e)}
                    dataSource={data_source}
                />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }


}
```

nothing happened when i click second level plus button on table , how to solve this ? is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all i like to answer your first Question

> is this a bug?

No,this is not a Bug. 
This occurs when you don't set the unique key value to the each table row.
add this code snipt in to your both "Table" tags.

> rowKey = {e=> e._id}

ex:-

```
         <Table
                rowKey = {e=> e._id}
                className="components-table-demo-nested"
                columns={this.props.columns}
                expandedRowRender={(e)=>::this.expandedRowRender(e)}
                dataSource={data_source}
            />
```

Comment: You just saved a soul today! Thanks for taking the time to leave this comment, I was going insane over this.